# NIC problem with VLAN?

Tags: networking, server

I have istalled 3 NIC interfaces:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f6:c1:9e:5e:8a:be
      inet addr:192.168.100.2  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::f4c1:9eff:fe5e:8abe/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:3392026 errors:0 dropped:5100 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2611567 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:364902559 (364.9 MB)  TX bytes:266616444 (266.6 MB)

eth1   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:06:4f:00:eb:ad
      BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth2   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2e:07:4a:15:69:7b
      inet addr:192.168.6.13  Bcast:192.168.6.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::2c07:4aff:fe15:697b/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:300 (300.0 B)

eth0.3 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f6:c1:9e:5e:8a:be
      inet addr:192.168.3.6  Bcast:192.168.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::f4c1:9eff:fe5e:8abe/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:25415 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4038 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:6251410 (6.2 MB)  TX bytes:300030 (300.0 KB)

eth0.4 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f6:c1:9e:5e:8a:be
      inet addr:192.168.4.2  Bcast:192.168.4.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::f4c1:9eff:fe5e:8abe/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1578482 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1548426 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:128703459 (128.7 MB)  TX bytes:138923674 (138.9 MB)

lo     Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:5430180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:5430180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:6389482336 (6.3 GB)  TX bytes:6389482336 (6.3 GB)
```

Interface eth0 with VLANs works as I expected but eth2 can`t make any connection. No ping respone at all.

dmesg | grep -i "eth"

```
[    2.405807] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    2.405815] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[    2.405833] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth2: link is not ready
[    3.972335] 8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eth0
[    4.947006] 8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eth2
```

Please note I have no VLAN configuration with eth2.